# How to document jQuery-ui widgets with jsdoc-toolkit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, documentation, jsdoc

How can i document this widget so the toolkit can expose the methods and options.
Everything I have tried will not see anything inside the closure.

```
/**
* @fileOverview
* @version 1.0
*/

(function($) {
    "use strict";
    $.widget('mynamespace.nameofwidget', {

        // foo should show up in the docs
        options: {
            'foo': 'bar'
        },

        // public function name and parameters should be documented
        myPublic function () {
            // code here....
        },

        // private function no need to document
        _create: function () {
            // code here....
        },

        // private function no need to document
        _setOption: function (key, value) {
            // code here....
        },
    });

})(jQuery);
```

[EDIT]

Here is my config file

```
{
    // source files to use
    _: ['js/test/'],

    // document all functions, even uncommented ones
    a: true,

    // including those marked @private
    p: true,

    // use this directory as the output directory
    d: "js/docs/",

    // use this template
    t: "jsdoc-toolkit/templates/jsdoc",

}
```

Here is the command line command I am using.

```
java -jar jsdoc-toolkit/jsrun.jar jsdoc-toolkit/app/run.js  -c=js/docs/conf/ilo.conf
```

[UPDATED CONF]

```
{
    "opts": {
        "destination": "../js/out/",
        "private": true
    },
    "tags": {
        "allowUnknownTags": true
    },
    "source": {
        "include": [ "../js/test" ],
        "includePattern": ".+\\.js(doc)?$",
        "excludePattern": "(^|\\/|\\\\)_"
    },
    "plugins": [],
    "templates": {
        "cleverLinks": false,
        "monospaceLinks": false,
        "default": {
            "outputSourceFiles": true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `@name` and `@namespace` directives (alternatively, you can use the `@name` directive on a constructor function). Below is a sample documentation for your code:

```
/**                                                                                                                                                                                           
 *@fileOverview                                                                                                                                                                               
 *@version 1.0                                                                                                                                                                                
 *                                                                                                                                                                                            
 * @namespace mynamespace.nameofwidget                                                                                                                                                        
 */                                                                                                                                                                                           

(function($) {                                                                                                                                                                                
    "use strict";                                                                                                                                                                             
    $.widget('mynamespace.nameofwidget', {                                                                                                                                                    

        /**                                                                                                                                                                                   
         * @name mynamespace.nameofwidget#foo                                                                                                                                                 
         * @description Description of Foo                                                                                                                                                    
         */                                                                                                                                                                                   
        options: {                                                                                                                                                                            
            'foo': 'bar'                                                                                                                                                                      
        },                                                                                                                                                                                    

        /**                                                                                                                                                                                   
         * @name mynamespace.nameofwidget#myPublic
         * @function
         * @description some description                                                                                                                                                      
         */                                                                                                                                                                                   
        myPublic: function () {                                                                                                                                                               
            // code here....                                                                                                                                                                  
        },                                                                                                                                                                                    

        /**                                                                                                                                                                                   
         * @name mynamespace.nameofwidget#_create                                                                                                                                             
         * @function
         * @private                                                                                                                                                                           
         * @description will not show up in HTML docs, but the comments are good to have                                                                                                      
         */                                                                                                                                                                                   
        // private function no need to document                                                                                                                                               
        _create: function () {                                                                                                                                                                
            // code here....                                                                                                                                                                  
        },                                                                                                                                                                                    

        /**                                                                                                                                                                                   
         * @name mynamespace.nameofwidget#_setOption                                                                                    
         * @function
         * @private                                                                                                                                                                           
         * @param {String} key                                                                                                                                                                
         * @param {String} value                                                                                                                                                              
         * @description will not show up in HTML docs, but the comments are good to have                                                                                                      
         */                                                                                                                                                                                   
        // private function no need to document                                                                                                                                               
        _setOption: function (key, value) {                                                                                                                                                   
            // code here....                                                                                                                                                                  
        }                                                                                                                                                                                     
    });                                                                                                                                                                                       

})(jQuery);
```

Note that if the `-p` parameter is used on the command line, the `@private` directive will **not** hide commands from the generated documentation.

See [this page](http://usejsdoc.org/about-namepaths.html) for more information about namepaths and [this page](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-private.html) for more information about the `@private` directive.

Comment: I copy and pasted this into a file and ran it on that file. I get "WARNING: Trying to document XXXX as a member of undocumented symbol mynamespace.nameofwidget." for each method in the widget, and when I look at the outputed index.html nameofwidget is no where to be found, but under the File Index the nameofwidget.js file is listed and was parsed.

Comment: I am not getting any errors with jsdoc v3.2.0. What version are you using?

Comment: Maybe the issue is I am using jsdoc-toolkit which is described as a wrapper for jsdoc. Am trying to install it now via node.js but it is recognizing git so might take me a bit to figure out how to get git to work with node.js

Comment: I used this command from the readme to install it: `npm install -g git://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc.git`.

Comment: Yeah that gives me an error "npm ERR! not found: git". I ended up downloading it manually and adding it to my project, I got it to run with "jsdoc -c conf.json" and it creates the file nameofwidget.js.html in the out folder but nothing is listed in the index.html I posted the new conf file

Comment: Try running it _without_ `conf.json` like so: `jsdoc test.js`.

Comment: running "jsdoc ../js/test/nameofwidget.js" gives same results as running with the config

Comment: Did you copy my code exactly or manually add the directives? Did you remember to add the `@namespace` directive at the top?

Comment: wow good call yeah I missed that. It is actually documenting now. But It is documenting everything in duplicates. Like the member foo is there twice.

Comment: Very odd when I ran it on my project using the config the dups went away, so the config must be setting it properly. Anyway it works now. I can't thank you enough.